# JQuery HTML Form prevent going to a new url

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have the following in my index.html file:

```
<div class="block" id=search_block> <form id= "search"> <input class = "search_textbox" type="text" name="ticker" value="" ></form> </div>
```

To prevent going from a new page, if someone hits the enter key, I have the following:

```
      $('.search_textbox').keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 13) {
            alert("in here");
            e.preventDefault();
            createStock();
        }
    });
```

Unfortunately, that doens't seem to work and I'm not quite sure why! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats because you have written keyDown on form.

It has to be on Input

```
<input class="ticker_input" type="text" name="ticker" value="" onsubmit="CreateStock();">

$('.ticker_input').keypress(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 13) {
    e.preventDefault();
    CustomJavaScriptFunction();
  }
});
```

Comment: Nope, didn't work. Still the same thing. I've put revised code up now.

Comment: @user1357015 i checked with keydon on fiddle it wroking perfectly